# Command Line from within Sublime Text

Tags: command-line, java, sublime-text-2

I recently switched from Notepad++ to Sublime Text 2, and it's amazing. There's one thing I'd appreciate and that's compiling my files from the same environment. Sublime text has a console and a command pallets, but none of them can execute regular windows commands.

So for example, I'd simply like to run `javac program.java` and `java program` from a console from within Sublime Text.

Is such thing possible yet? If so, how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

The "Show Console" button shows the Python console that is embedded into Sublime Text not the usual OS terminal. If you want to open a terminal in the folder containing the edited file you can try [Sublime Terminal](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/terminal) package.

EDIT: @Darren: if so then look in the Internet on how to run terminal commands from python shell, Google has a lot of links to them.

Comment: Running terminal commands from the python shell does help and can temporarily be used as a solution, but it's not the ultimate solution where the console would act as a regular shell console.

Comment: Ok, so straight away - there is no way that you can show there an usual system terminal. You can try to extend Sublime Text with a plugin, but AFAIK there's no such plugin at the moment (something is written [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=11755) ) I though think that it's not a really needed feature because system terminal will still be better, and there's no common interface between terminals in different OS.

Answer (score 2):

If you're mainly looking to compile and run Java programs, then a [build system](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_processing/build_systems.html) (see full reference [here](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html)) is what you're looking for. From the `Preferences` menu, select `Browse Packages...` and navigate to the `Packages/Java` folder, and open the `JavaC.sublime-build` file:

```
{
    "cmd": ["javac", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.java"
}
```

This assumes that `javac` is in the `PATH` used by Sublime, you may need to edit it to fit your system's setup. You can run this build system by first saving your `.java` file, then selecting either `Tools -> Build System -> JavaC`, or `Tools -> Build System -> Automatic`, then hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> (<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> on Mac).

To run the resulting `.class` file, modify `JavaC.sublime-build` to the following:

```
{
    "cmd": ["javac", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.java",
    "working_dir": "${project_path:${file_path}}",

    "variants": [

        { 
            "name": "Run",
            "cmd": ["java", "$file_name"],
            "shell": true,
            "env": {"CLASSPATH": "/path/to/jar/files:/path/to/more/jars"}
        }
    ]

}
```

You can then use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> (<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> on Mac) keyboard combo to execute the `Run` variant of the build system. The `"working_dir": "${project_path:${file_path}}"` line executes the build from the directory containing your `.sublime-project` file, if you don't have one it defaults to the directory containing your `.java` source. `"shell": true` runs the `"cmd"` through the shell, whether it's `cmd.exe`, `bash`, or whatever you choose. Otherwise, it just outputs through the Sublime console. The `"env"` dictionary allows you to add Key:value pairs of environment variables you might want to set just for the build session. It can be in the `"Variants"` section or the main one, depending on your needs.

For lots of details, check out the two links I provided at the beginning - together they contain a ton of information and some useful examples of build systems. You can also browse through the `Packages` directory's subfolders and check out any `.sublime-build` files you find for ideas - their names are listed under `Tools -> Build System` (i.e., the "Python" build system is found in `Packages/Python/Python.sublime-build`).

---

In response to your original question, Sublime just isn't architected to support a full-fledged terminal emulator. While you can run arbitrary commands using Python's [`subprocess.Popen()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor), I prefer to use the fantastic [`SublimeREPL`](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL) plugin (available through [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net)) along with [`IPython`](http://ipython.org). There are a bunch of [dependencies](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/install/install.html), but `easy_install ipython[all]` should take care of most of that for you, as would installing through a package manager like `MacPorts`, `yum`, `apt-get`, etc. For Windows, precompiled binaries are available from Christoph Gohlke's [Python Extension Packages for Windows repository](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#ipython), which includes links to all the required and optional dependencies. Make sure you're using the [python.org](http://python.org) installation of Python, though.

Once you have Python and IPython installed on your system and in Sublime's `PATH`, and SublimeREPL installed, go to `Tools -> SublimeREPL -> Python -> Python - IPython` and you should be up and running momentarily. To execute a shell command, [simply prefix it with `!`](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/tutorial.html#system-shell-commands) - for example:

```
In [1]: !ls
```

will list the contents of the current working directory, while

```
In [2]: files = !ls
```

will assign those names to a variable. Be aware, however, that commands like `!cd ..` won't actually change the current working directory, you'll need to run:

```
In [3]: import os
In [4]: os.chdir('..')
```

to do that. The documentation for the `os` module's [Files and Directories functions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#files-and-directories) is very useful here (change the `2` in the URL to a `3` if you're using Python 3) - which brings up another strong point of this system: You can have multiple versions of Python on your system, and not have to depend on the stripped-down version of 2.6 that ships with Sublime Text 2. Save the following to `Packages/User/SublimeREPL/config/Python/Main.sublime-menu` and customize for your tastes:

```
[
    {
        "id": "tools",
        "children":
        [{
            "caption": "SublimeREPL",
            "mnemonic": "r",
            "id": "SublimeREPL",
            "children":
            [
                {
                    "caption": "Python",
                    "id": "Python",
                    "children":[
                        {
                            "command": "repl_open",
                            "caption": "Python 3",
                            "id": "repl_python3",
                            "mnemonic": "p",
                            "args": {
                               "type": "subprocess",
                               "encoding": "utf8",
                               "cmd": ["/opt/local/bin/python3", "-i", "-u"],
                               "cwd": "/Users/YourNameHere/Development/python",
                               "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
                               "external_id": "python3",
                               "extend_env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"}
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "command": "repl_open",
                            "caption": "IPython 3",
                            "id": "repl_ipython3",
                            "mnemonic": "p",
                            "args": {
                                "type": "subprocess",
                                "encoding": "utf8",
                                "cmd": ["/opt/local/bin/ipython", "-i", "--pylab=osx", "--colors=NoColor"],
                                "cwd": "/Users/YourNameHere/Development/python",
                                "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
                                "external_id": "Ipython",
                                "extend_env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"}
                             }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }]
    }
]
```

Now you can have custom menu options that will survive `SublimeREPL` upgrades from Package Control, and run REPLs with different options, working directories, what have you.

Hopefully some of this is of some use to you, please let me know how it works for you.

Comment: This is such a complete and thorough answer, HOWEVER, as solid as it is, build systems are too much of a hassle for me. Plus they're only useful for compilation but I still can't run arbitrary commands through the console.

Comment: I'm just surprised that there is no plugin which turns the python terminal into a shell terminal.

Comment: I just love this text editor so much I'm thinking about digging into plugin dev for it. Only if the python console could be a shell console...

Comment: I’m giving this a +1 simply for this line: `"env": {"CLASSPATH": "/path/to/jar/files:/path/to/more/jars"}` *None* of the other answers I’ve seen on here, SO, or anywhere else (so far) have acknowledged the need for specifying a `CLASSPATH` for external libs, and thus were only good for basic hello-world programs. Unfortunately, modifying the build-system every time you switch projects is not practical, but at least it is doable at all, which is more than I can say for every other “solution” I’ve seen so far.

Comment: @Synetech you can define build systems in your `.sublime-project` files. See [the docs](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_management/file_management.html#projects).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible now.
You can compile and run your code entirely in ST, and it's very quick/simple.
There's a recent ST package called Javatar that can do this.
https://javatar.readthedocs.org